# IBM DB2 for i SQL (iSeries) - Removing a character from end of a field using update

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a product table called PDPRODP - for certain styles within this table I used a concat statement to add a full-stop to their description (PRDESC), I now wish to remove this full stop.

The descriptions are varying length, the field max size is 30 characters and I need to physically remove the full-stop rather than using a select statement to trim the full-stop.

I tried;

```
UPDATE PDPRODP SET PRDESC = PRDESC-1 where PRSTYLE = 1234
```

But I got this error:

```
Character in CAST argument not valid.
```

I also tried this following some googling;

```
UPDATE PDPRODP SET PRDESC=LEFT(PRDESC, LEN(PRDESC)-1)
WHERE PRCOMP = 1 AND PRSTYL = 31285
```

But got this error:
    `LEN in *LIBL type *N not found.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LENGTH

```
UPDATE PDPRODP SET PRDESC=LEFT(PRDESC, LENGTH(PRDESC)-1)
WHERE PRCOMP = 1 AND PRSTYL = 31285
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Madhivanan, I've just cracked it though and came to post the answer. I ended up with your statement also but it didn't work due to whitespace, but this did work;


`UPDATE PDPRODP1`
 `SET PRDESC=LEFT(PRDESC, LENGTH(TRIM(PRDESC))-1)`
 `WHERE PRCOMP = 1 AND PRSTYL = 31285`

Comment: @RDKells Side note: If it's VARCHAR **and** needed TRIM(), is it understood that something updated the column inappropriately? Or was that only a side-effect of when the full-stop was added?

Comment: Presumably RTRIM is both more desirable and more _correct_ for the intent than is TRIM. For TRIM, if an expression is specified as the only argument, "then the characters are removed from both the end and the beginning of the string" for which any value with any prepended blanks would be corrupted. The _safest_ change is to explicitly replace **only** a _full stop_ as last character thus allowing the statement to run more than once; i.e. only multiple periods-as-suffix would be trimmed in later runs. Either a predicate selects only values ending with a period, or the expression limits change.

Answer (score 3):

The [REPLACE()](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscareplace.htm) function can search for all occurrences of some string, and substitute another in its place. You might search for your full-stop, and replace it with a zero-length string `''`.  This would be handy in cases where your search string may not always be at the end.